How to use Cauchy integral theorem to evaluate this real integral $\int_0^\infty x^\alpha e^{ix}dx$?
I recently learnt that to evaluate the integral
$$\int_0^\infty x^\alpha e^{ix}dx\quad\text{with }-1<\alpha<0, $$
we have to apply Cauchy's Integral Theorem to deform the integral from the real axis to the imaginary axis, and the result is $e^{i\pi(\alpha+1)/2 }\Gamma(1-|\alpha|),$ I want to ask how does the deformation work and how could we get the result?
As a similar example with the above, how could we get $\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{ikx}dx=2\pi\delta(k)$ using Cauchy's Integral Theorem? Thank you very much for any helps and solutions!

Have a look at this post
